# How to connect to Database with Spring Boot application.yml

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, psql

I have the PostgreSQL Database called `db`.

And here is my `application.yml`

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    database: postgresql
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    schema: classpath:/schema.sql
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

When I run my project, nothing happens, no errors and sure `schema.sql` that has a script for creating a table also does not work.

I have these dependencies in my `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I don't understand why nothing happens even with no errors.

I hope for your help.

Comment: Are you using JPA? If so why there is no JPA dependency?

Comment: I have added `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` a few minutes ago but any changes

Comment: What doesn't happen according to you that shuld happen? This question is to vague and contains too little information imho.

Comment: @M.Deinum Connection to database should work and at least `schema.sql` should create one table